# CallMethodAction binding to Button fails

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

There are no errors. I am trying to learn MVVM. The setup is simple. I get no output when clicking on the button. Xaml should be ok since I have produced interactions part in Blend by dragging behavior to the button. Note: My intention to use methods, but not command, since commands cover only click, but not for example DoubleClick.

```
<Window
x:Class="MVVM_1.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVM_1"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="525"
Height="350"
mc:Ignorable="d"
 >
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Button  x:Name="button"
        Width="75"
        Margin="198,168,0,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Content="TestMethod">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown" SourceName="button">
                <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="MethodTesting" 
                                     TargetObject="{Binding}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MVVM_1
{
public class ViewModel 
    {

    public static void MethodTesting()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Success!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have a `sender` and `EventArgs` as parameters in your `MethodTesting`? Also I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21820832/2029607) which should help with your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a command to bind the control to the click event.

[MVVM - Commands, RelayCommands and EventToCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx)

Instead of:

```
public static void MethodTesting()  
{
    MessageBox.Show("Success!");
}
```

Use [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16314968/3956566):

```
public ICommand ButtonClickCommand 
{
    get { return new DelegateCommand<object>(FuncToCall, FuncToEvaluate);}
}

private void FuncToCall(object context)
{
    //this is called when the button is clicked
    MessageBox.Show("Success!");
}

private bool FuncToEvaluate(object context)
{
    //this is called to evaluate whether FuncToCall can be called
    //for example you can return true or false based on some validation logic
    return true;
}
```

Also under this [How do you create an OnClick command in WPF MVVM with a programmatically created button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904356/how-do-you-create-an-onclick-command-in-wpf-mvvm-with-a-programmatically-created) - [is another great example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36904525/3956566).

Comment: I am trying to avoid commands, and use methods. Methods promise more since for example DoubleClick is not supported by command.  I should have stated that in my question. I will update the question now.